apache superset error - failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run ${BUILD_CMD}" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
I got this error while installing Apache superset in docker, and I can't fix it.
I've been trying to search for this issue, but no answers have come up.
How can I fix it?
1842.9 react-hooks/exhaustive-deps: React Hook useMemo has a complex expression in the dependency array. Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked.
1842.9     59 |         {} as { [key in string]: string },
1842.9     60 |       ),
1842.9   > 61 |     [JSON.stringify(data)],
1842.9        |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1842.9     62 |   );
1842.9     63 |
1842.9     64 |   const handleChange = (values: string[] | string | undefined | null) => {
1842.9
1842.9 WARNING in src/filters/components/TimeGrain/TimeGrainFilterPlugin.tsx:87:6
1842.9 react-hooks/exhaustive-deps: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 
1842.9

...

1842.9 ERROR in packages/superset-ui-demo/storybook/shared/components/ResizableChartDemo.tsx:22:35
1842.9 import/no-unresolved: Unable to resolve path to module '@storybook/types'.
1842.9     20 | import React, { useState, ReactNode } from 'react';
1842.9     21 | import { styled } from '@superset-ui/core';
1842.9   > 22 | import { DecoratorFunction } from '@storybook/types';
1842.9        |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
1842.9     23 | import ResizablePanel, { Size } from './ResizablePanel';
1842.9     24 |
1842.9     25 | export const SupersetBody = styled.div`
1842.9
1842.9 webpack 5.89.0 compiled with 1 error and 406 warnings in 1684702 ms
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run ${BUILD_CMD}" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


To get started with Superset, follow these steps:

Ensure you have Node.js installed on your system.
Open your terminal and run the following command to clone the Superset repository:


git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/apache/superset.git



After cloning the repository, navigate into the Superset directory and start the application using Docker Compose. Run the following command:


docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up


